# Disable past date is not working in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar

```
 $("#txtdoe").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

to disable past date but it is not working i checked the issue in console but there is no error in it.
I am attaching my screenshot of the calendar
please have a look.

[image]

Comment: [Try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1dkjfso/30/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `minDate: +0` with working snippet.

```js
$("#txtdoe").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd ',
  minDate: +0 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtdoe" ng-model="Licence.DateOfExpiration" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the min date to today's date:

```
var today = new Date();
$("#txtdoe").datepicker({ minDate: today  });
```

Comment: try to set it explicetely to 'now'

Comment: can you please include your HTML code too and where do you call that js?

Comment: here is my html

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtdoe" ng-model="Licence.DateOfExpiration" required>

Comment: i am using angular also in it

Comment: quite important info. In your controller associated to that datepicker, add this too: `Licence.DateOfExpiration = new Date();`

Answer (score 1):

you can put minDate to now

```
$("#txtdoe").datepicker({ minDate: 'now'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It will help you.

JavaScript

```
var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#txtdoe").datepicker({    
    changeMonth: true,   
    minDate: dateToday,  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabling past dates means, I guess you're trying to disable the dates before the current date. You can achive it by

```
var today = new Date();
$("#txtdoe").datepicker({ startDate: today });
```

If you want the other way around (disabling future dates), put endDate instead of startDate.